# C# building permutations with wildcards using recursion

Tags: c#, sql, recursion

So I'm having a mind melt.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to do the following:

I have an input that defines how many wildcards I can use UP TO, in this example we say 2.

I have a string, ABCDEFGH.

I need to create an array of all the different ways those 2 wildcards can feature in the string so that I can feed it into an SQL query.

By hand we can do.

```
_BCDEFGH
A_CDEFGH
AB_DEFGH
ABC_EFGH
ABCD_FGH
ABCDE_GH
ABCDEF_H
ABCDEFG_
```

And using our limit of 2.

```
__CDEFGH
_B_DEFGH
_BC_EFGH
_BCD_FGH
_BCDE_GH
_BCDEF_H
_BCDEFG_
A__DEFGH
A_C_EFGH
A_CD_FGH
A_CDE_GH
A_CDEF_H
A_CDEFG_
AB__EFGH
AB_D_FGH
and so on...
```

For compatability with SQL I need to use the wildcard character as an underscore_.

Can someone help me understand how to structure my loops? Bare in mind that limit of wildcards isn't always 2, it is a variable.

This isn't a question of Regex or matching, I need to be able to create these variations of a string.

Comment: And your question? Write it for me?

Comment: Look at your examples. See how the underscore is moving? That should give you a very good idea of how your loops should perform their iterations.

Comment: @I4V Not to be rude but it's in the post... "Can someone help me understand how to structure my loops? Bare in mind that limit of wildcards isn't always 2, it is a variable."

Comment: @JohnKoerner I understand how the nesting should work, but I can't hard code the nesting because I don't know how many loops I need to nest, given the wildcard number can be anything. If I had a wildcard of 2, I know to nest 2 loops to iterate over, but what if the number is unknown...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get something like this

```
 List<String> permutations(String original, int numberOfWildcards) {
        //add 1 more wildcard to each posible position in the original string
        List<String> perm = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (original[i] != '_')
                perm.Add(original.Substring(0, i) + "_" + original.Substring(i + 1, original.Length));
        }
        if ( numberOfWildcards == 1)
        {
              return perm;
        }

        //now if we need to search deeper we recusively do this for each substring
        List<String> permWithMoreWildmark = new List<String>();
        foreach (var str in perm)
        {
            permWithMoreWildmark.AddRange(permutations(str,numberOfWildcards-1));
        }
        return permWithMoreWildmark;
    }
```

the trick is to try to solve the problem for 1 deep first and then try to figure out the recursion

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and parse what you've proposed and see if it helps me :)

Comment: Got it working as needed, thanks for the help, good approach. Honestly wouldn't have figured it out by myself.